# How to centere grid or canvas when maximize the window in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I create One grid in wpf. when maximize the window the grid size in increased.So i want to center the grid when i maximize the window the increasing the grid size.Here the code i wrote.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Margin="188,69,179,172" Background="#FF1B9B7B"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF971A92" Height="70" Margin="233,139,315,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF97311A" Height="70" Margin="0,139,214,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="84"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Margin="188,69,179,172" Background="#FF1B9B7B" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF971A92" Height="70" Margin="233,139,315,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF97311A" Height="70" Margin="0,139,214,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="84"/>
</Grid>
```

Dont forget to specify Height and Width to inner Grid .I hope this will help.

Comment: I am using Blend 4.I Create one canvas and set center align in both vertical and horizontal. But it is not working.

Comment: I have'nt used blend . but mannually the above code works fine.